# combine mysql data from 2 tables to 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on a PHP page and I need some help in mysql so I have this database where they are e.g 2 tables

table one has 
ID, score and speed

table two has
ID, gameID and wins

I want to create a third table where
ID, score and wins are together and another column where gameID is now called gID

I know I can make a relation between them but I don't want to do that, I want the data to sync live from table 1 and 2 to table 3

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a `view`.  Sample data and expected results would be helpful.  Presumably you just need to use a `join` and then alias your column name.

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? Unless you need lookup on table 3 to be really fast, it's better to use a join.

Comment: 'I know I can make a relation between them' - I'm not sure I even know what that means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you a `VIEW`.

Here is an example without really knowing how your tables are in relation. I make the assumption that `tab1.id = tab2.gameID`. Nevermind you use a view or not you will have to Join them.

```
CREATE VIEW tab3 AS
    SELECT 
           tab1.ID as ID,
           tab1.score as score,
           tab2.wins as wins,
           tab2. as gID 
       FROM tab1 
           LEFT JOIN tab2 ON (tab1.id = tab2.gameID);
```

Take a look at the [working example DBfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gfFe6uHdEsEEV4qTqV45ST/7)

More info on how to use a `VIEW` in the [Docs - Mysql VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)